# update subviews when function calls back in parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a parent view that is a uipageviewcontroller and in the sub page views I have a uiimage in the view. Problem is I need to grab these images before the sub view shows (in the background maybe). right now I have a function in a class like so:

```
   // these functions are in a class to model the data for each subview
    func loadImages(){
        if self.images != nil && self.images!.count > 0{
            self.loadFirst()
        }
        if self.location_id != nil && (self.images == nil || self.images!.count == 0) {
        ApiWrapper.getPictures(self.location_id!, completionHandler: self.imagesCallback)
        }

    }
    func imagesCallback(cardImagesArray: [CardImage]){
        println("images callback")
        self.images = cardImagesArray
        self.loadFirst()
    }
    func loadFirst(){
        if self.images!.count > 0 {
            self.images![0].getData()
        }
    }
```

I am calling loadImages in the parent view for the next five "pages" in the array for uipageviewcontroller. Problem is when I swipe to the next view and the images aren't loaded yet when the "image callback" is executed it doesn't update the view. How can I update the view when the imagesCallback is executed? imagesCallback is in a class model of the data that each screen displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple different options on how to do this:

1. Implement a returnImageToDisplay on the parent pageviewcontroller, then do:

   ```
   var parent = self.parentviewcontroller? as theSubClassedPageViewController
   var image = parent.returnImageToDisplay(some_identifier)
   ```

   2.Subclass the child UIViewController you are using as a page, then do a similar thing as 1.- get the instance handler and call a method with the data as the argument.

In my opinion 1. is easier to implement.